# Method call from multiple controllers in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, methods, controller

I need to save images onto multiple controllers (bids, articles, users, etc), so it would be great to have a method that I could call from any of those controllers, what is the best way that I could implement that and how?

PS: I need such function/method because I resize, rename, crop, etc and I want to keep absolute coherence throughout my uploads

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'save images onto multiple controllers'. If you are saving the images using an Eloquent model then you can add a processing method to the model and override and add the processing functionality into the store/update methods maybe.

Comment: *I need to save images onto multiple controllers (bids, articles, users, etc),* -- so, you want to save images and have that method callable from some differing controller? you could make some class and put them somewhere in app directory, then call them.. (assuming you used proper `namespace` and `use`)

Comment: @BagusTesa Exactly, I want to call the same method from various controllers from which I need to save the images onto the disk exactly in the same way in many of them.

So I just create a new class that ISN'T a model, right?

Comment: @SantiagoCapdevila yes, you can add a custom class. however, do pay more attention on file location, file name, and namespace if my memory serves me right, laravel mostly uses [psr-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for autoload generation.. well, take app directory as example by noting their **file location, file name, and namespace** you'll able to make custom class safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is a create trait which contains relations and methods of the image model. Here is how I used it.

Crate trait Imageable.

```
 trait Imageable
 {

    public function images()
    {
       //code
    }
 }
```

Create ProductController.

```
<?php

use App\Traits\Imageable;

class ProductController  extends Controller
{
    use Imageable;


}
```

create  CollectionController.

```
    <?php
    use App\Image;
    use App\Traits\Imageable;
    use Eloquent as Model;

    class CollectionController  extends Controller
    {
        use Imageable;
    }
```

Use the property of trait with this reference.

```
$this->images();
$this->images();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the method to the Controller.php, because the controllers extend this controller, so all the controllers will have this method.